# CakePHP use different template for bake

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

On cakePHP I can create custom bake Templates. Is there a way to choose an alternative Template for one certain action?

Lets say I have these files:

```
/App/src/Template/Bake/Template/add.twig
/App/src/Template/Bake/Template/edit.twig
/App/src/Template/Bake/Template/view.twig
/App/src/Template/Bake/Template/index.twig
/App/src/Template/Bake/Template/index_alternative.twig
```

`bin/cake bake Template Articles` uses the first 4 template files of this list. What do I have to do to bake the index using the index_alternative template? Are there any parameters to contorl this? Kind of

```
bin/cake bake Template Categories index --use index_alternative
```

Or do I have to create own BakeTasks for that, or Themes? Or what is the way to go?

Comment: what are twig files?

Comment: @Antoniossss Template files that are processed with the [**Twig template engine**](https://twig.symfony.com/). Bake switched to using Twig as the new default recently.

Comment: How about passing `index_alternative` instead of `index`? The `Template` tasks `action` argument specifically refers to the template to use.

Comment: bake creates in `index_alternative.ctp` then. but i want to have an `index.ctp` file

Comment: Ah IC. Im away from cake for a while now

Comment: @MatthiasMoritz I see, then you're probably looking for the `alias` argument, ie the third argument, which defines the generated filename, ie you'd pass `index_alternative index`.

Comment: This is exact what I've looked for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it actually work for you? I've just tested it for the sake of testing it as I've never used it before, but it doesn't seem to do what the help says it would do - that looks like a possible bug to me.

Comment: @ndm yes, works for me.  Help says: `Will bake the template in <action> but create the filename after <alias>. (optional)` Maybe the <action> is a little confusing?

Comment: It's not overly clear, but the behavior is definitly different to what it says there. Maybe we're using different versions, with 1.5.5 it uses the alias as action/template as well as the alias (filename), ie it's basically like one only uses the second argument.

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#creating-a-bake-theme. You'd create a copy of the core files that you need, and set the theme...

Answer (score 0):

`cake bake template --help` states that the usage is:

```
cake bake template [subcommand] [options] [<controller>] [<action>] [<alias>]
```

Therefore, to choose one alternate template for a certain action, as in your example, you would have to specify the `alias` to be `index` and bake the `index_alternative` action, like:

```
cake bake template Categories index_alternative index
```